# How to make Jetpack Compose FlowRow RTL

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show a list elements in a `FlowRow` and I want the `FlowRow` direction to be RTL.
I tried using `CompositionLocalProvider` but it didn't change anything:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
    FlowRow(
        mainAxisSpacing = 10.dp,
        crossAxisSpacing = 10.dp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(4.dp),
        mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.Center
    ) {
        state.myList.forEach {
            MyItem(item = it)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1073). Until Google fixes the issue, instead of using `accompanist-flowlayout` library, you can use the following two files (originally by [Sven](https://github.com/brudaswen)). APIs are exactly the same.

**Layout.kt**

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints

internal enum class LayoutOrientation {
    Horizontal,
    Vertical
}

internal data class OrientationIndependentConstraints(
    val mainAxisMin: Int,
    val mainAxisMax: Int,
    val crossAxisMin: Int,
    val crossAxisMax: Int
) {
    constructor(c: Constraints, orientation: LayoutOrientation) : this(
        if (orientation === LayoutOrientation.Horizontal) c.minWidth else c.minHeight,
        if (orientation === LayoutOrientation.Horizontal) c.maxWidth else c.maxHeight,
        if (orientation === LayoutOrientation.Horizontal) c.minHeight else c.minWidth,
        if (orientation === LayoutOrientation.Horizontal) c.maxHeight else c.maxWidth
    )
}
```

**Flow.kt**

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.Layout
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.IntSize
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.LayoutDirection
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import kotlin.math.max

/**
 * A composable that places its children in a horizontal flow. Unlike [Row], if the
 * horizontal space is too small to put all the children in one row, multiple rows may be used.
 *
 * Note that just like [Row], flex values cannot be used with [FlowRow].
 *
 * @param modifier The modifier to be applied to the FlowRow.
 * @param mainAxisSize The size of the layout in the main axis direction.
 * @param mainAxisAlignment The alignment of each row's children in the main axis direction.
 * @param mainAxisSpacing The main axis spacing between the children of each row.
 * @param crossAxisAlignment The alignment of each row's children in the cross axis direction.
 * @param crossAxisSpacing The cross axis spacing between the rows of the layout.
 * @param lastLineMainAxisAlignment Overrides the main axis alignment of the last row.
 */
@Composable
public fun FlowRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    mainAxisSize: SizeMode = SizeMode.Wrap,
    mainAxisAlignment: FlowMainAxisAlignment = FlowMainAxisAlignment.Start,
    mainAxisSpacing: Dp = 0.dp,
    crossAxisAlignment: FlowCrossAxisAlignment = FlowCrossAxisAlignment.Start,
    crossAxisSpacing: Dp = 0.dp,
    lastLineMainAxisAlignment: FlowMainAxisAlignment = mainAxisAlignment,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Flow(
        modifier = modifier,
        orientation = LayoutOrientation.Horizontal,
        mainAxisSize = mainAxisSize,
        mainAxisAlignment = mainAxisAlignment,
        mainAxisSpacing = mainAxisSpacing,
        crossAxisAlignment = crossAxisAlignment,
        crossAxisSpacing = crossAxisSpacing,
        lastLineMainAxisAlignment = lastLineMainAxisAlignment,
        content = content
    )
}

/**
 * A composable that places its children in a vertical flow. Unlike [Column], if the
 * vertical space is too small to put all the children in one column, multiple columns may be used.
 *
 * Note that just like [Column], flex values cannot be used with [FlowColumn].
 *
 * @param modifier The modifier to be applied to the FlowColumn.
 * @param mainAxisSize The size of the layout in the main axis direction.
 * @param mainAxisAlignment The alignment of each column's children in the main axis direction.
 * @param mainAxisSpacing The main axis spacing between the children of each column.
 * @param crossAxisAlignment The alignment of each column's children in the cross axis direction.
 * @param crossAxisSpacing The cross axis spacing between the columns of the layout.
 * @param lastLineMainAxisAlignment Overrides the main axis alignment of the last column.
 */
@Composable
public fun FlowColumn(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    mainAxisSize: SizeMode = SizeMode.Wrap,
    mainAxisAlignment: FlowMainAxisAlignment = FlowMainAxisAlignment.Start,
    mainAxisSpacing: Dp = 0.dp,
    crossAxisAlignment: FlowCrossAxisAlignment = FlowCrossAxisAlignment.Start,
    crossAxisSpacing: Dp = 0.dp,
    lastLineMainAxisAlignment: FlowMainAxisAlignment = mainAxisAlignment,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Flow(
        modifier = modifier,
        orientation = LayoutOrientation.Vertical,
        mainAxisSize = mainAxisSize,
        mainAxisAlignment = mainAxisAlignment,
        mainAxisSpacing = mainAxisSpacing,
        crossAxisAlignment = crossAxisAlignment,
        crossAxisSpacing = crossAxisSpacing,
        lastLineMainAxisAlignment = lastLineMainAxisAlignment,
        content = content
    )
}

/**
 * Used to specify the alignment of a layout's children, in cross axis direction.
 */
public enum class FlowCrossAxisAlignment {
    /**
     * Place children such that their center is in the middle of the cross axis.
     */
    Center,
    /**
     * Place children such that their start edge is aligned to the start edge of the cross axis.
     */
    Start,
    /**
     * Place children such that their end edge is aligned to the end edge of the cross axis.
     */
    End,
}

public typealias FlowMainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment

/**
 * Layout model that arranges its children in a horizontal or vertical flow.
 */
@Composable
private fun Flow(
    modifier: Modifier,
    orientation: LayoutOrientation,
    mainAxisSize: SizeMode,
    mainAxisAlignment: FlowMainAxisAlignment,
    mainAxisSpacing: Dp,
    crossAxisAlignment: FlowCrossAxisAlignment,
    crossAxisSpacing: Dp,
    lastLineMainAxisAlignment: FlowMainAxisAlignment,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    fun Placeable.mainAxisSize() =
        if (orientation == LayoutOrientation.Horizontal) width else height
    fun Placeable.crossAxisSize() =
        if (orientation == LayoutOrientation.Horizontal) height else width

    Layout(content, modifier) { measurables, outerConstraints ->
        val sequences = mutableListOf<List<Placeable>>()
        val crossAxisSizes = mutableListOf<Int>()
        val crossAxisPositions = mutableListOf<Int>()

        var mainAxisSpace = 0
        var crossAxisSpace = 0

        val currentSequence = mutableListOf<Placeable>()
        var currentMainAxisSize = 0
        var currentCrossAxisSize = 0

        val constraints = OrientationIndependentConstraints(outerConstraints, orientation)

        val childConstraints = if (orientation == LayoutOrientation.Horizontal) {
            Constraints(maxWidth = constraints.mainAxisMax)
        } else {
            Constraints(maxHeight = constraints.mainAxisMax)
        }

        // Return whether the placeable can be added to the current sequence.
        fun canAddToCurrentSequence(placeable: Placeable) =
            currentSequence.isEmpty() || currentMainAxisSize + mainAxisSpacing.roundToPx() +
                    placeable.mainAxisSize() <= constraints.mainAxisMax

        // Store current sequence information and start a new sequence.
        fun startNewSequence() {
            if (sequences.isNotEmpty()) {
                crossAxisSpace += crossAxisSpacing.roundToPx()
            }
            sequences += currentSequence.toList()
            crossAxisSizes += currentCrossAxisSize
            crossAxisPositions += crossAxisSpace

            crossAxisSpace += currentCrossAxisSize
            mainAxisSpace = max(mainAxisSpace, currentMainAxisSize)

            currentSequence.clear()
            currentMainAxisSize = 0
            currentCrossAxisSize = 0
        }

        for (measurable in measurables) {
            // Ask the child for its preferred size.
            val placeable = measurable.measure(childConstraints)

            // Start a new sequence if there is not enough space.
            if (!canAddToCurrentSequence(placeable)) startNewSequence()

            // Add the child to the current sequence.
            if (currentSequence.isNotEmpty()) {
                currentMainAxisSize += mainAxisSpacing.roundToPx()
            }
            currentSequence.add(placeable)
            currentMainAxisSize += placeable.mainAxisSize()
            currentCrossAxisSize = max(currentCrossAxisSize, placeable.crossAxisSize())
        }

        if (currentSequence.isNotEmpty()) startNewSequence()

        val mainAxisLayoutSize = if (constraints.mainAxisMax != Constraints.Infinity &&
            mainAxisSize == SizeMode.Expand
        ) {
            constraints.mainAxisMax
        } else {
            max(mainAxisSpace, constraints.mainAxisMin)
        }
        val crossAxisLayoutSize = max(crossAxisSpace, constraints.crossAxisMin)

        val layoutWidth = if (orientation == LayoutOrientation.Horizontal) {
            mainAxisLayoutSize
        } else {
            crossAxisLayoutSize
        }
        val layoutHeight = if (orientation == LayoutOrientation.Horizontal) {
            crossAxisLayoutSize
        } else {
            mainAxisLayoutSize
        }

        layout(layoutWidth, layoutHeight) {
            sequences.forEachIndexed { i, placeables ->
                val childrenMainAxisSizes = IntArray(placeables.size) { j ->
                    placeables[j].mainAxisSize() +
                            if (j < placeables.lastIndex) mainAxisSpacing.roundToPx() else 0
                }
                val alignment = if (i < sequences.lastIndex) {
                    mainAxisAlignment
                } else {
                    lastLineMainAxisAlignment
                }

                val mainAxisPositions = IntArray(childrenMainAxisSizes.size) { 0 }
                when (orientation) {
                    LayoutOrientation.Horizontal -> with(alignment.toHorizontalArrangement()) {
                        arrange(
                            mainAxisLayoutSize,
                            childrenMainAxisSizes,
                            layoutDirection,
                            mainAxisPositions
                        )
                    }
                    LayoutOrientation.Vertical -> with(alignment.toVerticalArrangement()) {
                        arrange(mainAxisLayoutSize, childrenMainAxisSizes, mainAxisPositions)
                    }
                }

                placeables.forEachIndexed { j, placeable ->
                    val crossAxisSize = placeable.crossAxisSize()
                    val crossAxis = when (crossAxisAlignment) {
                        FlowCrossAxisAlignment.Start -> 0
                        FlowCrossAxisAlignment.End ->
                            crossAxisSizes[i] - crossAxisSize
                        FlowCrossAxisAlignment.Center ->
                            Alignment.Center.align(
                                IntSize.Zero,
                                IntSize(
                                    width = 0,
                                    height = crossAxisSizes[i] - crossAxisSize
                                ),
                                LayoutDirection.Ltr
                            ).y
                    }

                    val crossAxisPosition = crossAxisPositions[i] + crossAxis
                    if (orientation == LayoutOrientation.Horizontal) {
                        placeable.place(
                            x = mainAxisPositions[j],
                            y = crossAxisPosition
                        )
                    } else {
                        placeable.place(
                            x = when (layoutDirection) {
                                LayoutDirection.Ltr ->
                                    crossAxisPosition
                                LayoutDirection.Rtl ->
                                    crossAxisLayoutSize - crossAxisPosition - crossAxisSize
                            },
                            y = mainAxisPositions[j]
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun FlowMainAxisAlignment.toHorizontalArrangement() =
    when (this) {
        FlowMainAxisAlignment.Center -> Arrangement.Center
        FlowMainAxisAlignment.Start -> Arrangement.Start
        FlowMainAxisAlignment.End -> Arrangement.End
        FlowMainAxisAlignment.SpaceEvenly -> Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        FlowMainAxisAlignment.SpaceBetween -> Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        FlowMainAxisAlignment.SpaceAround -> Arrangement.SpaceAround
    }

private fun FlowMainAxisAlignment.toVerticalArrangement() =
    when (this) {
        FlowMainAxisAlignment.Center -> Arrangement.Center
        FlowMainAxisAlignment.Start -> Arrangement.Top
        FlowMainAxisAlignment.End -> Arrangement.Bottom
        FlowMainAxisAlignment.SpaceEvenly -> Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        FlowMainAxisAlignment.SpaceBetween -> Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        FlowMainAxisAlignment.SpaceAround -> Arrangement.SpaceAround
    }

/**
 * Used to specify how a layout chooses its own size when multiple behaviors are possible.
 */
// TODO(popam): remove this when Flow is reworked
public enum class SizeMode {
    /**
     * Minimize the amount of free space by wrapping the children,
     * subject to the incoming layout constraints.
     */
    Wrap,
    /**
     * Maximize the amount of free space by expanding to fill the available space,
     * subject to the incoming layout constraints.
     */
    Expand
}

/**
 * Used to specify the alignment of a layout's children, in main axis direction.
 */
public enum class MainAxisAlignment {
    /**
     * Place children such that they are as close as possible to the middle of the main axis.
     */
    Center,

    /**
     * Place children such that they are as close as possible to the start of the main axis.
     */
    Start,

    /**
     * Place children such that they are as close as possible to the end of the main axis.
     */
    End,

    /**
     * Place children such that they are spaced evenly across the main axis, including free
     * space before the first child and after the last child.
     */
    SpaceEvenly,

    /**
     * Place children such that they are spaced evenly across the main axis, without free
     * space before the first child or after the last child.
     */
    SpaceBetween,

    /**
     * Place children such that they are spaced evenly across the main axis, including free
     * space before the first child and after the last child, but half the amount of space
     * existing otherwise between two consecutive children.
     */
    SpaceAround;
}
```